# Cómo correr QT Designer en QT5 Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

He instalado PyQT5 sobre Windows mediante pip3 install PyQt5. Sin errores. De hecho desde Python se puede importar el módulo. Problema: ¿cómo puedo correr Qt Designer? No veo ningún designer.exe o similar. 
Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt Designer no viene con **pyqt**, sino que forma parte del paquete [**PyQt5-tools**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools), debes instalarlo de forma independiente:

```
py -3 -m pip install PyQt5-tools
```

Una vez instalado correctamente te vas a donde tengas instalado Python en tu sistema y lo encontrarás en:

> Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer.exe

Si instalaste Python en el directorio por defecto (Windows 10) debes encontrarlo en:

```
C:\Users\TU_USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\designer.exe    
            ^                                        ^
            |                                        |
  Cambiar por tu usuario               Cambiar por tu versión de Python
```

Puedes crear un acceso directo para más comodidad.

Comment: Totalmente cierto. ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!